# Two Actions on an Android Snackbar?

Tags: android, modal-windows, microinteractions

The Android Design guidelines encourage '0-1 actions, not dismiss or cancel' for Snackbars (actionable toasts).

My question is about cases when a Snackbar is the best option to not interfere with the workflow, but there are two plausible actions users might want to take from the Snackbar. For instance, our Snackbar might look something like this. (Where **VIEW** would navigate to a feedback page, showing the consequences of the action)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6Fs6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Is this a definite no-no with regards to convention & guidelines, or is there wiggle room here?

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a snackbar, but the google website uses a small popup with two links as call to action to download the native app. The two actions are  clearly styled as primary and secondary and the touch targets are large.

[image: Google mobile app popup]

Comment: What is that dialog called? Or is that from the website?

Comment: That's from the website.

Comment: From the design it is more similar to a [banner](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Android is all about wiggle room

Of course, that's fodder for it's critics too. If your user needs two actions, given 'em two actions.

My concern in your example is the proximity of two fundamentally different actions. In mobile , you always have to consider the accidental tap with adjacent actions. Accidentally viewing when you wanted to undo would be an irritating experience.

If your user has a reasonably accessible path to view the change through the static UI, I'd cut it down to undo in the snackbar (which is an expected function there).

Comment: Great point about the proximity of the two actions. This raises the question for me, is the body of a snackbar ever actionable? Would it make sense to have an UNDO button, and have the VIEW action be called when tapping on the rest of the bar? Of course this would be completely pointless if that is not a common pattern.

Comment: It's not common. It could also be confused as an alternate way to trigger the undo. Seems hard to distinguish the two actions in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is a questionable design.**

Snackbars should not require too much cognitive load from the user, since they typically disappear automatically or are otherwised dismissed quickly with a tap.  Providing two options gives the user too much to think about in this limited time frame.

I already find it rather hairy to try to tap "undo" quickly enough, before the notification disappears, after I accidentally deleted an email in GMail.  Providing two options would be panic-inducing.

The need to do this quickly will magnify the problem of proximity that plainclothes mentions.

Also, your particular design raises workflow issues, as well: **what if I want to view an action then decide whether to undo it?**

I'd say find another way to do this.